# Silverlight - Notifications Usability Best Practice

Tags: .net, silverlight, c#-4.0, notifications

I want to know if there is a siverlight client notification best practice, right now i'm using a MessageBox.Show(), but this doesn't seem the right approach to a RIA application, shall i create a new Child Window, NotificationWindow, maybe a label that will contain what i'm trying to notify.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted industry standard for client notifications in Silverlight is to have a custom panel that flies in from the left. It should squash a little bit horizontally for a moment when it stops in the middle of the screen. Then when the user clicks OK, it should fly off the right of the screen (preferably rotating).

Cartoon sound effects are optional, and should be disabled by default.

Alternatively, you could simulate a dreary gray dialog from Windows 3.0, but you will never win the Internet with that approach.

Comment: In case you are wondering, I am *completely* serious in my answer. Non-technical users are accustomed to working with solid objects in the real world. Brief animations in interface elements can make an application much more useable to those people. (Or so I am told.)

Comment: Do you know where can i find an example of that approach?

Comment: I'm Giving you the answare, even thought i would like to see it implemented, thanks man.

Comment: @Bongo Sharp - Yeah, I tried to find an implementation on the web, but I haven't yet been successful. I have seen this multiple times in seminars and podcasts, but I have not been able to locate them!